# Vue Cli 3 and Firebase service worker registration

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, service-worker, vue-cli, workbox

I've used Vue-cli 3 to create a Vue app and I've been trying to incorporate FCM into it. However, I've been working on it for two days and I still cannot get it working.

First, here's my

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.8.1/firebase- app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.8.1/firebase-messaging.js');
var config = {
  messagingSenderId: "69625964474"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function (payload) {
  console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload)
  // Customize notification here
  const notificationTitle = 'Background Message Title';
  const notificationOptions = {
      body: 'Background Message body.',
      icon: '/firebase-logo.png'
  }

  return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions)
});
```

```

One solution that sorta works is I moved this file into the `public` folder and register it in `App.vue` using

```
const registration = await navigator.serviceWorker.register(`${process.env.BASE_URL}firebase-messaging-sw.js`)
messaging.useServiceWorker(registration)
```

However, then I'll be having two service workers (the other one from Vue itself).

I tried to modify `vue.config.js` instead trying to work with Workbox by adding the following config:

```
module.exports = {
  pwa: {
    name: 'My App',
    themeColor: '#4DBA87',
    msTileColor: '#000000',
    appleMobileWebAppCapable: 'yes',
    appleMobileWebAppStatusBarStyle: 'black',

    // configure the workbox plugin
    workboxPluginMode: 'InjectManifest',
    workboxOptions: {
      // swSrc is required in InjectManifest mode.
      swSrc: 'public/firebase-messaging-sw.js'
      // ...other Workbox options...
    }
  }
}
```

And then register it again in `App.vue`:

```
const registration = await navigator.serviceWorker.register(`${process.env.BASE_URL}service-worker.js`)
messaging.useServiceWorker(registration)
```

Then I got the following error instead:

[image]

If you are confused by the files I mentioned or how the directory of my project looks like, what I did was simply creating a PWA using vue-cli 3. And I left most of the structure untouched.

And I set up firebase in `main.js`:

```
import firebase from '@firebase/app'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

const config = {
  apiKey: process.env.VUE_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.VUE_APP_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  databaseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_DATABASE_URL,
  projectId: process.env.VUE_APP_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.VUE_APP_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.VUE_APP_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID
}

firebase.initializeApp(config)
```

Then in `App.vue`:

```
import firebase from '@firebase/app'
import '@firebase/messaging'

const messaging = firebase.messaging()
messaging.usePublicVapidKey('PUBLIC_KEY')
```

Comment: There is a space in the first firebasejs URL that causes a 404 page that is HTML. `https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.8.1/firebase- app.js` If you remove the space does it work?

Comment: kevguy did you get this to work?

Comment: @HugovanSchalkwyk You can take a look here: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/1481#issuecomment-398304170

Answer (score 0):

The service worker is by default disabled in development mode, so running it in development will cause an HTML error page to be returned, this is the reason you are getting text/html error
You can find detailed explanation here [LINK](https://github.com/jeffposnick/create-react-pwa/issues/11#issuecomment-273540766)